# I wanted to ask about "EGO", how philosophers have defined ego?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, identity, self

Many philosophers have touched the topic of "Ego". For instance, Freud, Buddha, Iqbal and many others. We all have fragile ego. In simple terms, how ego can be defined? What is the most suitable explanation of it in modern era? I see many people get hurt, when we don't agree to their perspective. How can we handle this?

Comment: Ego=self?......

Comment: See [What does the term "ego" really mean?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/what-does-the-term-ego-really-mean)

Comment: The concept of ego by Iqbal suggests it as self. I might be wrong but that was what I studied.

Comment: @Nihilist Unfortunatley I do not know whether Iqbal gave a definition of his understanding of ego. I assume that as a poet and mystic Iqbal made again a different use of the term. I assume the work of the orientalist Annemarie Schimmel builds a bridge between Iqbal and European, in particular German conceptions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annemarie_Schimmel

Comment: The ego as defined by psychoanalysts is very different to that defined by Islam (and by extension, Muslims like Iqbal).

Comment: Could you re-phrase that to include broadly what you see as the best - perhaps best two or three - definitions, and why they leave you unsatisfied? Correct me, and I think SE is not meant to handle Questions like 'how philosophers have defined ego?'

Comment: @Nihilist I vote for reopen. Possibly the title could be changed into: Which different definitions gave philosophers and psychologists for the terms “ego” and “self”?

Comment: In writings and talks about Advaita Vedanta, Self Realization and Nonduality, 'ego' refers to the part of the mind that sees itself as separate, that acts for its own benefit, and tends to use a lot of concepts, discursive thought, argumentative reasoning. In other words, pretty much what you see here, ha ha :-) And *everywhere*. The part that needs to be mastered in order to be what you can fully be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First of all: EGO as a technical term has been defined in different
   ways by different philosophers and psychologists. There does not exist a common definition, accepted by all psychologists and philosophers.

   Definitions are not right or wrong, because everyone has the free
   choice how to name the concept he/she uses.   Hence it is best to
   prefix each discussion about concepts like EGO, the self, atman etc.
   by a definition what is meant -  so far concerning “handling the
   problem”.
2. Ad Sigmund Freud: He distinguishes three different parts of the
   psyche: *id*, *ego*, *superego*. The set of unconscious processes, e.g.,
   the bodily drives, are called *id*. The *ego* as a set of essentially
   conscious processes, and the unconscious processes of the *superego*.
   The superego processes mostly form the conscience of a person.

   Freud
   also describes the function of these three components, for an
   introduction see [id, ego, superego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_superego). But note that Freud partly revised his structural model during the long
   development of his theory.

   Note: Freud uses the term ego without any
   connotation of egoism.
3. Ad Hinduism: Nearly all Hindu schools subscribe to the technical
   term *Atman* (The Self), considered as the core part of the person.

   Unfortunately the term Atman is ill-defined. Several passages from
   the Upanishads try to describe the term by certain metaphors. They
   often agree, what the core of the human psyche is **not**, but they
   never give a clear positive definition what it is.  The problem
   becomes even worse when the term is related to the other key term of
   the Upanishads, the term Brahman. Several Upanishads subscribe to the
   equality

   > Atman = Brahman

   Then Atman means the core of the person
   and Brahman the core of the universe. But that’s no more than an
   equation with two indeterminates and does not clarify the concepts at all.
4. Ad Buddhism: All Buddhist schools subscribe to the doctrine of
   no-Self or *an-atta* (= no Atman) or śūnyatā. Here it is claimed that
   the human person does not have a fixed core. Instead the psyche is formed by
   temporary, short living perceptions.

   There are many discussions
   between Indian schools, e.g. between the Hindu school of nyāya and
   Buddhist philosophers about the existence or non-existence of Atman.
5. Ad neuroscience: Besides psychology also neuroscience has developed models of the
   ego, also without connotation with egoism. The value of a technical
   term is its usability in developing theoretical models which
   explain certain aspects from the domain of investigation.

   Neuroscience explicates the term "self" in form of a self-model. Concerning the self-model and its link to the world-model of a person see  [Thomas Metzinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Metzinger.)
   in his book "Being No One. The Self-Model Theory of Subjectivity". Metzinger proposes these two linked models as an interface between the philosophy of mind and neuroscience.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster lists](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ego) the three basic meanings of the word.

At the most basic level, *ego* denotes that part of the perceiving and thinking entity which is not anything else. Little children as well as many animals seem not to be entirely aware of that distinction; it is at least in part a learnt thing.<sup>1</sup>

You touch the second meaning, self-esteem, in your own question ("a fragile ego").

Freud, who I would not directly count as a philosopher, used the word as the "conscious" part of our psycho-physical being.

---

<sup>1</sup> And if we think about it, in the beginning of a child's existence its limits are not well defined at all; even birth and cord-cutting, fundamental as they are, do not sever the connection to the mother completely. There is an ongoing bodily, emotional and, if you want, spiritual connection.